# Дописать данные в excel файл

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

у меня есть пустой эксель файл. Есть функция, которая реализует запись данных в файл, нужно сделать так, чтобы многократные вызовы этой функции с разными параметрами делали записи в этот файл, не перезаписывая его (как у меня сейчас), а добавляли данные. Т.е. чтобы в первой ячейке было значение1, во второй, которая под первой второе и тд.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что я делаю не так?

```
    public void fileWritter(boolean error,String filename, String testNum,int numrow) { 
        String result = "";
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet newSheet = workbook.createSheet("results");
        Row row = newSheet.createRow(numrow);
        
        
        try {
            FileInputStream filein = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
            XSSFWorkbook workbook1 = new XSSFWorkbook(filein);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook1.getSheetAt(0);
            if(error==false) {
                result += "Test "+testNum+" finished without errors!";
                row.createCell(0).setCellValue(result);
            }else {
                result += "Test "+testNum+" finished with errors!";
                row.createCell(0).setCellValue(result);
            }
                
             filein.close();
             FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream(new File(path));
             workbook.write(fileout);
             fileout.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

}

    }
```

Comment: Используйте вместо createCell метод get

Comment: Ну естессно row.getCell(X).setValue - как то так это должно выглядеть